# When reading a book

Tags: gerunds

*When reading a book, he heard a strange sound coming from outside.*

*By reading a book, he heard a strange sound coming from outside.*

I would like to ask whether these two sentences are grammatically OK and have the same meaning. In the case of the first one I am not sure whether the conjunction can be used together with the gerund.

Comment: Grammatically correct, yes. But the second verb is wrong: hear, heard, heard. NOT: heared. By + verb + ing=OK, When + verb + ing=OK.

Comment: They are both grammatically okay, but the second strikes me as odd since I can't see how the act of reading a book can cause one to hear a strange sound from outside

Comment: It does not matter if it is strange. It is grammatically correct. The person could be psychotic, for instance...

Comment: Of course it matters! The OP asked if the meanings were the same, but the apparently infelicitous adjunct makes it difficult to tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"By" + gerund is **never** temporal, **always** instrumental.

> By reading a book I discovered how economics works.

"By reading a book, he heard a strange noise coming from outside" means that reading a book was the method he used to hear the noise.

"When" + gerund is temporal, so it fits here; but it tends to treat the event as an indivisible unit. If you are talking about something which happened during the event, "while" is more common:

> While reading a book, he heard a strange noise coming from outside">

Comment: The sentences are both grammatical. That doesn't make them make semantic sense. But then, that was not the question.

Answer (score -1):

i. When reading a book, he heard a strange sound coming from the outside.

ii.  By reading a book, he heard a strange sound coming from the outside.

*i* is unusual and *ii* might be ungrammatical.

*i* rather implies the implausible

i'. Whenever he read a book, he always heard a strange sound.

The following would be more plausible and more "grammatical":

iii.  While reading a book, he heard a strange sound.

iii'. Whilst reading a book, he heard a strange sound.

Both iii and iii' (British usage) imply a one-time event.

With reference to *ii*, *by* marks an instrumental, agentive, or locative semantic relation:

iv.  He opened the bottle by hitting it with a hammer. (instrumental, causative, manner)

v.  He put the bottle by the window. (location)

vi. The sound was caused by the book. (agentive, a "passive sentence")

*vi* seems closest in possible meaning to *ii*, but it is hard to imagine how *the book could cause his hearing* so, I'm afraid we can only regard *ii* as ungrammatical.